# Port Redirection on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, osx-lion, port-forwarding, ipfw

I have tried to solve this issue using pf but with no luck. Basically, I am trying to redirect incoming port 443 traffic to port 22. I have tried to set up a rule in a file and load it in pf but I get syntax error. Can anyone with more experience with pf provide some insight? Here's what I've attempted:

```
pass in on en1 proto tcp from any to any port 443 rdr-to 127.0.0.1 port 22
```

and

```
pass in quick proto tcp to port 443 rdr-to 127.0.0.1 port 22
```

I've been able to do this in MacOSX Snow Leopard with ipfw:

```
sudo ipfw add 1443 forward 127.0.0.1,22 ip from any to any 443 in
```

but it doesn't work in Lion (it gives me an Invalid Argument error).

Comment: This is a guess, but is anything else running on port 443 that has a higher rule than your script? What happens if you move your rule to the top of the ipfw chain?

Comment: thanks for your reply. when I said ipfw doesn't work in lion, I should have said that I get an "invalid argument" error without much information on what is wrong with the command. the same command though works fine in Snow Leopard.

Comment: Check out this link, which I pointed out in another firewall question: http://serverfault.com/q/102416/3914

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you don't want to forward `any to any` but something like `any to me`,
this works fine for me in Lion

sudo ipfw add `1443 fwd 127.0.0.1,22 tcp from any to me 443 in`

Answer (score 1):

Since mac os X 10.7 apple uses pf instead of ipfw . It is easy to configure pf with IceFloor. Check it out: http://www.hanynet.com/icefloor/index.html

Comment: OS X 10.8.5 still uses ipfw.